# How Two table join in symfony 2.8 using repository

Tags: linux, windows

I have two table user and site. I have to fetch data matcjh site.user_id = user.id Please help me. I am Using Symfony framwork first time.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Table join In Symfony 2.8.

SiteSetingsEntity

/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Rippl\FrontBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="sitesetings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

User Entity - 
You have to make new field name is site entity
/** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Rippl\FrontBundle\Entity\SiteSetting", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "merge"}) */